# Redirect a Dynamically formed Servlet (Name) to a Static Servlet

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, junit

In our product we have a feature called HTTP Adapter. By this, from our application we can fire any HTTP request. However, while writing the JUnits I came across in a situation as explained below:

Please note that the Servlet names are user configurable and we can dynamically replace the Servlet name. For example, if you are providing a Servlet name as T$date in configuration, our application will automatically replace the $date placeholder with the current date (e.g T08012015 will be the Servlet name).

I am using embedded tomcat in my JUnits. But my problem is while writing for the above case, how will I get a Servlet whose name contains current date as I will be executing the JUnitTestSuite every day. I have an option to dynamically create the Servlet before executing the test case and then delete it. But this looks bit cumbersome to me.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for all the Date stuff. Joda Time supports setting a fixed date for now() in tests. [1]

```
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(millis);
```

[1] http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Change_the_Current_Time

Comment: Thank you for the response. But its not clear to me how will I use Joda Time in this context.